# Bounty description textarea is cut in mobile web theme

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, bounties, mobile-web

We can start bounties in the mobile theme just fine, choose amount of reputation, reason for bounty, and then...

> [image]

The box is buried deep into the left invisible margin, and no matter how hard I tried to scroll, tap, resize, knock, could not get to see what I write.

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: The mobile design still needs several improvements. The chat presents a similar pattern to this (+1).

Comment: @AndreSilva yep, chat is totally unuseable on mobile device, but it's already reported. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed as part of project ["Mobile web refresher"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237518/mobile-web-refresher-part-2), thank you team! :)

> [image]